# Print on same line (overwrite) does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

A snipet of my code look like this:

```
print(' ⦾ Loading subcase decryption table...', end='')
codes_dict = load_codes(codes_file)
print('\r ✓ Subcase decryption table loaded.')
```

The purpose of that is to have a message displayed as a feedback that something is running (and what) like so:

`>> ⦾ Loading subcase decryption table...`

Once it finishes, it has to be **replaced** (on the same line) by this:

`>> ✓ Subcase decryption table loaded.`

This does not work though. Instead, the first print statement has to start with the return character as well `'\r'` as in `print('\r ⦾ Loading subcase decryption table...', end='')` but I just do not understand why..

It would make perfect sense if it was in a loop like so:

```
for i in range(76):
    print('\r {:7.2%}'.format((i + 1) / 76), end='')
```

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: I usually do `print('whatever', end='\r')` so my strings look nice and clean

Comment: Are you running this in an interactive shell? Does it work if you run the script externally?

Comment: @AndrasDeak It is just the standard PyCharm output shell. By externally you mean call it from cmd or another script for example?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yeah, but why? Why on the original one?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do it on the original one.  `\r` is a carriage return, but  you're already sitting at the beginning of the buffer.  try running `print('1 test test test', end='\r'); print('2 test')` from interactive shell.  You should see a final output of `2 test test test`

Comment: `print(' ⦾ Loading subcase decryption table...', end=''); print('\r ✓ Subcase decryption table loaded.')` just prints the second one in python 3.5; cannot reproduce. So yeah, I'd try calling it from cmd, there might be some interference from PyCharm's shell.

Comment: PyCharm's output window is not a perfect emulation of a real console and it has some quirks. If you run the script from a real shell it will probably work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason (most likely) is that your shell is [line buffered](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html). Any text sent to it is buffered up to certain length or until a `\r` is encountered. The reason to do so is to minimize overhead if the program writes out single characters, postponing the rendering stuff to the latest yet user-convenient moment.

> The use of line buffering for interactive devices implies that output
>   messages ending in a newline will appear immediately—which is usually
>   what you want. Output that doesn’t end in a newline might or might not
>   show up immediately, so if you want them to appear immediately, you
>   should flush buffered output explicitly with fflush

Line buffering is why your first line never appears; if you prefix the line with a `\r`, you effectively flush the line buffer.

The solution usually is to write directly to the underlying stream or force a buffer flush.